# Update multiple elements in an array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document like following in my stocks collection in mongodb.

```
{ _id: 'xRMuRBhqRLgASyQyW',
  History: 
     [ { orderId: '12032017001877',
         status: 'COMPLETED',
        },
       { orderId: '22122017002450', 
        status: 'PROCESSED',
        },
        { orderId: '22122018002450', 
        status: 'DEPOSIT',
        }  
     ] 
 }
```

I want to iterate through all document in `stocks` collection and add a field `flag: true` if status is not `'PROCESSED'`.

Comment: If there's just one such sub-document in every array, you can use mongodb positional operator $. if several, then most likely you'll have to read the document, change its contents on the client, and save back (possibly as a series of surgical `$set` commands, like `$set: {'History.2.flag': 'true'}`)

Comment: Sergio Tulentsev , sir Are you talking about the History Array ? No there is many item in that array.  And I am trying to change my database using mongo shell so there is no client side.

Comment: Mongo shell IS the client side.

Comment: No sir I am using Nosqlbooster

Comment: But that's a gui, not a shell. Anyway, shell is a client too. Everything is a client, except the database itself.

Comment: Thank you sir. It was my mistake

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `$[]` the all positional operator will work for multiple documents as well...

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: ooh, that's a new one (to me). Thanks, TIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using script.

```
db.stocks.find().forEach(function (e) {
  var modified = false;
  e.History.forEach(function (o) {
    if (o.status != "PROCESSED") {
      o.flag = true;
      modified = true;
    }
  });
  if (modified) {
    db.stocks.save(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: I found this is the best one. Most suitable to my problem

Answer (score 13):

You need to use the all [$[] positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator to update each element in the array

```
db.collection.update(
   { "History": { "$elemMatch": { "status": { "$ne": "PROCESSED" } } } }, 
   { "$set": { "History.$[].flag": false } },
   { "multi": true }
)
```

Comment: Sir, it is a nice one but I think two extra parameters(basically false and true as they are suitable here for me) should be added for 'upsert' and 'multi'. Here I am writing because of 'multi' so that it could change more than one documents.

Comment: You can use `multi` true for multiple documents but don't know why `upsert`here?

Comment: Sir Using 'upser' to false we can ensure that even if there is no any document to satisfy the criteria , a new document will not be created

Comment: by default `upsert` is `false`... So there is no need to write it... But if you want to ensure then you can put it to `false`

Comment: Bingo!! This is the perfect answer for an update each element in the array.

Comment: simply P E R F E C T

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by using '$' operator. Something like:

```
 db.stocks.update( {"history.status" : { $not: "PROCESSED" } , 
                { $set: {"history.$.flag": true }} , 
                false , 
                true);
```

Comment: Won't work for multiple matches in the same array.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar @Anthony but 
a two extra parameter( for `upsert` and `multi`) are added. For reference You can check [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update).

```
db.stocks.update(
    { "History": { "$elemMatch": { "status": { "$ne": "PROCESSED" } } } }, 
    { "$set": { "History.$[].flag": false }},
     false,              // show that if there is not any document with specified criteria , it will not create a new document.
     ture              // according to document of mongodb if multi is true then more than one document will be updated, other wise only one document will be updated.
)
```