# Update Mongodb array object

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection in mongodb

```
{
  _id:124,
  array:[{
    _id:1
    name:'name1'
   },
   {
    _id:2
    name:'name2'
   }
  ]
}
```

How can i update name all the name field of Array 'array', with "Name" with single query?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update multiple elements in an array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206841/update-multiple-elements-in-an-array-in-mongodb) and [update multiple elements in array mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279886/update-multiple-elements-in-array-mongodb?rq=1)

Comment: are you looking for renaming the array key `name` to `Name` ?

Comment: no, the below answer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 3.6 or more

```
db.collection.update({_id: 124}, {$set: {"array.$[].name" : "Name"}});
```

Checkout this [Link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) for more

Comment: [update api docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) it doesn't look like they support it currently as arrayFilter is no mentioned in the available options, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: it seems, mongoose 5.x supports this.